# Is it possible to turn off antialiasing in SceneKit to make pixel art images sharp?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I want to add textures in my game similar to Minecraft which has sharp pixel art. Anyone know how to do it?

EDIT:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg9SE.png

This is what I am talking about. The edges of the pixels should be very crisp but they are all blurred together.

PROBLEM SOLVED:

I had to change the texture filtering on the SKTexture instead of the diffuse itself. This solved the problem and now I have crisp textures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds that you want to turn off texture filtering:

```
aMaterial.diffuse.minificationFilter = SCNFilterModeNearest;
aMaterial.diffuse.magnificationFilter = SCNFilterModeNearest;
```

Comment: Agreed. For the original poster: aliasing is generally considered to be when the edges of things show an obvious staircase-type pixel pattern. Then a single straight line is thought to have adopted the alias of a series of horizontal or vertical slabs that touch at their corners. Antialiasing makes it look like a straight line again. Texture filtering is about how you guess which colours should fall between sampled points on a texture; as per Toyos you appear to want a 'nearest' (i.e. colour at (x, y) is the colour of the nearest sample) filter.

Comment: @Toyos actually this didn't work. The textures are still blurry when scaled up. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

additionally, you can set the scene's `antialiasingMode` to `SCNAntialiasingModeNone`.